# How to fix this Minecraft Fullscreen issue?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just purchased a new computer and decided to play a game on Minecraft. However the graphics in game look a little weird when I full screen. When it's minimized in a smaller window it looks normal. Anyone know anything about this?

Using a 4k monitor by Samsung and a MSI RTX 2060

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the menus and GUI being small? Go to video settings and change GUI Scale to medium or large.

Comment: Its not that i have tried that the thing is its just small if i turn the settings down completly u cant see any chat or anything

Comment: That's exactly what GUI scaling does. Try what I told you to.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try tampering with your Fov (Field of View) setting until you get it to the right look for the size and shape of the screen.